# grunt-sass Minified css Sourcemap Incorrect

Tags: css, node.js, sass, gruntjs

So I'm using grunt-sass to compile my sass stuff but I'm running into one issue.

```
sass: {
        options: {
            outputStyle: 'compressed',
            sourceMap: true
        },
        dist: {
            files: {
                '<%= pkg.dir.css %>/styles.css': '<%= pkg.dir.sass %>/styles.scss'
            }
        }
    },
```

Everything is fine but the sourcemap created is pointing the css to completely incorrect locations. This works perfectly fine if the css is not minified.

Has anyone encountered this or have any ideas to what the issue is?